# Como estilizar uma aplicação WPF para ficar parecida com aplicações do Windows 8 (estilo Metro)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, windows-7

Eu trabalho em uma empresa onde eles utilizam um sistema que lembra muito o Windows 8, mesmo eu estando na máquina Windows 7.

O que eu precisava fazer é desenvolver um sistema desktop pelo meu computador (Windows 7) mas precisava deixar com a mesma cara, parecido com o Windows 8.

Exemplo:

Ao invés de usar o  - `MessageBox.Show`. Gostaria do `MessageDialog`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você só consegue fazer isto criando um estilo próprio ou usando algum que outra pessoa fez. Não quer dizer que vai ficar perfeito mas fica bem próximo. Alguns exemplos:

- [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)
- [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)

Existem outras pagas.

Fora isto, pergunte para quem fez o sistema como foi feito. É a única forma de fazer ficar igual.

Comment: Amigo, se eu quiser aproveitar e usar um desses prontos, como eu consigo utiliza-lo? precisa instalar...? Se vc tiver algum tutorial ou video, eu agradeceria... ^^

Comment: Sim, precisa instalar. Um deles está cheio de informações de como usar, é só ler lá. Provavelmente fazer um curso, comprar um livro para ir entendendo dos os nuances do que precisa ser feito. Não é algo simples que se aprende do dia para noite, é preciso bastante esforço. Só com tutoriais você não consegue fazer coisas tão complexas. Os tutoriais são receitas prontas, qualquer vírgula diferente você não saberá como resolver. Precisa adquirir o fundamento.

Comment: @EmersonMoraes Você já alguma vez usou WPF?

Comment: @bigown, Farei isso. Muito obrigado mesmo... (:

Comment: @ramaral, nunca usei, esta sendo a primeira vez.

Comment: Então você está com um problema grande em mãos! WPF não se aprende a usar de um dia para o outro.

Comment: Vou correr atras para aprender a usar esse WPF, preciso!